# How to pronounce /æ/ in American English?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, ae-raising

This one is really hard for me because I feel like it has at least two pronunciations.

**Examples**:

- *bad* /bæd/ where it sounds more like /ee/
- *practice* /præktəs/ where it sounds more like /aa/

Can someone help me with the correct pronunciation? Is there a rule for it? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: They both sound the same to me. It would sound like /ee/ if it were "bead"

Comment: I meant the IPA /e/ not the American e

Comment: It might be regional, but I still feel like I use the same pronunciation of "a" in "bad" and "practice".

Comment: My name is "Barry" and I use the same "a", but I have a cousin whose pronunciation always sounded more like "Beery". Maybe that's how you pronounce "bad"?

Comment: @PeterShor EFL students haven’t learned to ***unhear*** phonetic allophones yet. Vowels do sound a tiny bit different when checked by an unvoiced consonant like in *practice* than when checked by a voiced one like in *bad*, or in *tight* versus *dyed*, but that doesn't change which phoneme is ***meant***. See also [*bath*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/bath) and [*fast*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/fast), [*hand*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/hand) and [*lamb*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/lamb).

Comment: @peyton00 Every native speaker pronounces their own language “correctly” in that particular idiolect’s accent; please see [/æ/ raising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//%C3%A6/_raising) and the duplicates I’ve marked above.
All these many pronunciations are “correct”: 
[*head*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/head),
[*ten*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/ten),
[*hand*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/hand),
[*rain*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/rain),
[*eight*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/eight).